# How to set up environment variables when using aws-serverless-express

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, environment-variables

I am using aws-serverless-express for deploying an express api on aws lambda. I followed the aws-serverless-express repository example (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/tree/master/examples/basic-starter) to deploy the api and it works, but now I don't know how to set up environment variables in express code then after the express deployment I can see and edit those environment variables on lambda console. I didn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 2):

In the repository you mentioned, the `cloudformation.yaml` file has the function definition called `YOUR_SERVERLESS_EXPRESS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME`. you can define an  attribute called `Environment` under that. see the example below.

```
YOUR_SERVERLESS_EXPRESS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ./
    Handler: lambda.handler
    MemorySize: 1024
    Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
    Timeout: 30
    Environment:
      Variables:
        SOME_VAR: value   
    Events:
      ProxyApiRoot:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
          Path: /
          Method: ANY
      ProxyApiGreedy:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
          Path: /{proxy+}
          Method: ANY
```

Comment: glad to be of help. just for your future reference https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment